# Perforce change-submit trigger to run script on client

Tags: perforce

I've been looking around at various StackExchange posts, Perforce forum entries, etc. for a solution to the following problem, and would be grateful for your guidance and experience!

**Problem Description**

I want to be able to initiate **from** the Perforce server a series of validation steps on the ***client side*** on files opened within a changelist before allowing the changelist to be submitted.

For example, I wish to ensure that if a file is opened for add, edit, or remove as part of a changelist, that a particular related file will be treated appropriately based on a matrix of conditions for that corresponding file:

- Corresponding file being opened for add/edit/remove
- Corresponding file existing on disk vs. not existing on disk
- Corresponding file existing in depot vs. not existing in depot
- Corresponding file having been changed vs. not having been changed relative to depot file

These validation steps must be initiated before the submit is accepted by the Perforce server. Furthermore, the validation must be performed on the client side since I must be able to [reconcile offline work](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.2/p4v/using.offline.html) with the copies on clients' disks.

**Components**

- Perforce 2017.2 server
- MacOS and Windows computers submitting to different branches

**Initial Attempts**

- Initial design was a strictly client-side [custom tool](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v17.2/p4v/advanced_options.custom.html), but this is not ideal since this would be a change of the flow that users are familiar with, and I would also have to implement a custom GUI.
- Among other approaches, I considered [creating triggers in 2017.2](https://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/doc/manuals/p4sag/#P4SAG/scripting.trigger.creating.html%3FTocPath%3DUsing%2520triggers%2520to%2520customize%2520behavior%7CCreating%2520triggers%7C_____0); however, even if I were to use a [change-content](https://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/doc/manuals/p4sag/#P4SAG/scripting.triggers.submits.content.html%3FTocPath%3DUsing%2520triggers%2520to%2520customize%2520behavior%7CTriggering%2520on%2520submits%7C_____2) trigger with all the changelist files available on the server, I would not be able to properly perform the validation and remediation steps.
- Another possibility would be using a [change-submit trigger](https://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/doc/manuals/p4sag/#P4SAG/scripting.triggers.submits.submit.html%3FTocPath%3DUsing%2520triggers%2520to%2520customize%2520behavior%7CTriggering%2520on%2520submits%7C_____1) and to use the [trigger script variables in 2017.2](https://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/doc/manuals/p4sag/#P4SAG/scripting.triggers.variables.html) to get the client's IP, hostname, client's current working directory, etc. so that you could run a script on the server to try to connect remotely to the client's computer. However, running any script on the client's computer and in particular operating on their local workspace would require credentials that most likely will not be made available.

**Desired Approach**

I would love to use a change-submit trigger on the Perforce server to initiate a script/bundled executable on the client's computer to perform p4 operations on their workspace to complete the validation steps. However, references that I've found (albeit from years ago) indicate that this is not possible:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061840
- https://perforce-user.perforce.narkive.com/rkYjcQ69/p4-client-side-submit-triggers
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150792/updating-files-with-a-perforce-trigger-before-submit

Thanks again for reading and for your help!

EDIT: I posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582562/perforce-change-submit-trigger-to-run-script-on-client) to see if I could get some insight from a broader audience :D

Comment: This is a cool question, but please don't cross-post - delete one of your questions and leave the other up.